# Maximum flow for a set of switches and lights

Tags: python, algorithm

There are switches and lights that are walled and one switch can only be connected with one light. The lights, switches, and walls are given x,y points in this form.

```
Walls = [(1,2),(1,5),(8,5),(8,3),(11,3),(11,1),(5,1),(5,3),(4,3),(4,1),(1,1),(1,2)]

Lights = [(2,4),(2,2),(5,4)]  # In red can only be turned on by one switch

Switches = [(4,4),(6,3),(6,2)] # In green can only turn on one light

graph = {}

residual = {}

def ccw(A,B,C):
    return (C[1]-A[1]) * (B[0]-A[0]) > (B[1]-A[1]) * (C[0]-A[0])
# Return true if line segments AB and CD intersect
# Source: http://bryceboe.com/2006/10/23/line-segment-intersection-algorithm/
def intersect(A,B,C,D):
    return ccw(A,C,D) != ccw(B,C,D) and ccw(A,B,C) != ccw(A,B,D)
def visible(pt1,pt2,Walls):
    x1,y1 = pt1
    x2,y2 = pt2
    for i,wall in enumerate(Walls[:-1]):
        x3,y3 = wall
        x4,y4 = Walls[i+1]
        if intersect((x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4)):
            return False
    return True

def edges(L,M):

    # Empty dictionary that will store the edges
    graph['End'] = []
    for i in range(0, len(L)):  # for all the switches stores them as the key
        graph[M[i]] = []
    for switch in range(0, len(M)):   # for all the switches check to see what lights are visible
        for light in range(0, len(M)):
            if visible(M[switch],L[light],Walls) == True:
                graph[M[switch]].append(L[light])    # If the lights are visible store them in a list as the value
    graph['start'] = []
    for switch in range(0, len(M)):   # Connects the start (sink) to the switches
        graph['start'].append(M[switch])
    for light in range(0, len(L)):   # Connects each light to the End (sink)
        graph[L[light]] = ['End']
    return graph

def bfs_shortest_path(graphs, s, t): # from https://pythoninwonderland.wordpress.com/2017/03/18/how-to-implement-breadth-first-search-in-python/ Valerio Velardo
    # keep track of explored nodes

    global graph

    visited = []
    # keep track of all the paths to be checked
    queue = [[s]]

    # return path if start is goal
    if s == t:
        return "That was easy! Start = goal"

    # keeps looping until all possible paths have been checked
    while queue:
        # pop the first path from the queue
        path = queue.pop(0)
        # get the last node from the path
        node = path[-1]
        if node not in visited:
            newnode = graph[node]
            # go through all neighbour nodes, construct a new path and
            # push it into the queue
            for othernodes in newnode:
                newedgest = list(path)
                newedgest.append(othernodes)
                queue.append(newedgest)
                # return path if neighbour is goal
                if othernodes == t:
                    return newedgest, True

            # mark node as explored
            visited.append(node)

    # in case there's no path between the 2 nodes
    return "So sorry, but a connecting path doesn't exist :(", False

def maxflow(graphs):
        # Path taken
        graph = edges(Lights, Switches)
        path, tf = bfs_shortest_path(graph,'start','End')

        while tf == True:


            # for all the nodes in the graph delete them so they cannot be travelled to
            for i in graph['start']:
                if i in path:
                    graph['start'].remove(i)  # Removes first node in graph aka Switch
                    print(graph,'switch removed')
            for newnode in graph[path[1]]:
                if newnode in path:
                    graph[path[1]].remove(newnode)  # Removes next node aka Light
                    print(graph, 'light removed')
            for othernode in graph[path[2]]:
                    if othernode in path:
                        graph[path[2]].remove(othernode)
                        print(graph, 'end removed')
                        residual = graph
            return residual, 'residual graph'

print(maxflow(graph))
print(graph)

newgraph = {'End': [], (4, 4): [(2, 2), (5, 4)], (6, 3): [(2, 4), (5, 4)], (6, 2): [(5, 4)], 'start': [(6, 3), (6, 2)], (2, 4): [], (2, 2): ['End'], (5, 4): ['End']}

print(bfs_shortest_path(newgraph, 'start', 'End'))
```

The expected results should be a maximum flow output value that indicates that all 3 switches are connected to a light and are visible not interfering with any walls.

[Here is the book problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4jGA.png)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem you are trying to solve? I understood that you are somehow trying to connect the switches to lights. What are the requirements for that? And where do the walls come into the story?

Comment: You should clarify the concept of _ergonomic_ connections as well as how the walls are involved in this scheme of connecting switches to lights.

Comment: I have edited and added an image.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the challenge of this question is how to express the wiring problem as a flow problem. From there on, presumably you use the algorithms you have learned to calculate the flow.

We can conceptualise it like this:

- The source `s` connects to the switches `[sw1, ..., swN]` with an integer flow capacity of 1 (there is power going to each)
- Each switch *potentially* connects with each light bulb `[b1, ..., bN]` with an integer flow capacity of 1 (there is power to this bulb from this switch or not)
- Each bulb connects to the sink `t` with an integer capacity of 1 (the bulb is shining or not)

Each switch only has one power available, and each bulb can only accept a maximum of 1 power from switches, which effectively means they can only be connected to unique bulbs. If we rule out connections which go through walls and all our light bulbs are on, there must be an ergonomic layout (although we don't know what it is).

The broad steps of the algorithm are therefore:

- Work out which switches *actually* connect to each bulbs by ruling out any lines which intersect walls
- Construct the graph as described above (source to switches, switches to bulbs, bulbs to sink)
- Calculate the maximum flow of the graph

  - If the flow equals the number of bulbs then there exists an ergonomic layout

My guess is the algorithm for calculating flow has likely been provided earlier in the text, so I leave that part as an exercise for the reader :)